# Is it ok to use H1 after H2 in HTML5?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, web-standards

I was checking the article [20+ Professional Examples of Websites Using HTML5](http://designmodo.com/html5-examples/) to see the good semantic uses of new HTML 5 tags and I found that this website http://bit.ly/bfgatc is using `H2` before `H1` in Header.

[image]

Is it ok in HTML5?

Comment: I also wonder about this. Would it be "semantic" to place h1 below an h2? I always assume it would be. In HTML5 you can place multiple of the same header elements, so I believe this is also okay.

Comment: I think it makes sense in this situation, although I would have probably put the entire title in the H1. What seems odd are those IDs :)

Comment: @ScottSimpson - Yes. And while there is only one `hgroup` in `header` and there is only on `h1` and `h2` inside `hgroup` so all ids are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, neither of those have any business being separate headers, and they *definitely* shouldn't be in an `<hgroup>`. They're one header, and should be inside a `<header>`, or maybe even in a `<section>`. They don't have separate levels; one's just styled bigger than the other. It's not semantically correct to use the two in either order.

So what I would recommend is, instead of:

```
<header>
    <nav>...</nav>
    <div>
        <hgroup>
            <h2>...</h2>
            <h1>...</h1>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</header>
```

would be:

```
<nav>...</nav>
<header>
    <h1>I design user interfaces and strive for <strong>perfection.</strong></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: But if we go for your suggestion then Screen reader will not read as a heading.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: It's pretty flexible. I was just giving an example. Yes, it should be in an `<h1>`.

Comment: "hgroup" is used to make two headings into one, to prevent a new document node from forming

Comment: @JitendraVyas: Um... okay? And?

Comment: @minitech - I'm saying use of `hgroup` is ok here.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: No, it's not, it's what I'm saying. [The spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hgroup.html) says that it "represents a group of headings" - however, the heading in question is only *one* heading with very strong emphasis on the last word. Hence, it would be more semantic to use `<strong>`, and it's also much cleaner.

Comment: +1 I looked at the source again and now agree with your point. It's a single sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The  element has been removed from the HTML5 (W3C) specification. As Ryan said. It would be better to put it in a  tag.

Answer (score -1):

Why not? The spec for `hgroup` says:

> The hgroup element is typically used to group a set of one or more h1-h6 elements — to group, for example, a section title and an accompanying subtitle.

It seems to clear to me that a section title would be a H1 for example, and the subtitle a H2.

To expand: In this situation, it doesn't really make sense, but in general, there is technically nothing wrong with this (although a bit weird).

Comment: "a section title and an accompanying subtitle" is not the same thing as "an accompanying subtitle and a section title" here. The "and" is misleading, should be a "followed by". Though a SUBtitle can't precede a title. Here it should be a single heading or maybe a p+h1

Comment: The above is just an example, not the only thing it can be used for. The first part is the most important - to group a set of one or more h1-h6 elements.